# How to stop propagation on click, when you release the mouse outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about how to stop a event propagation.

Imagine i have two divs, one container and one contet.

When i make a complete click(mousedown and mouseup) inside the content, i can stop the propagation with preventDefault()

But if i make the mousedown inside the content, the move mouse outside and release the button, then the container handler is triggered.

I dont care about the event in the content, but i need to stop the event going trough the container in this situation.

I made a fiddle to test it:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lq7v50nw/

JS:

```
$('#container').on('click', function(){
alert('click in container')
});
$('#content').on('click', function(ev){
ev.stopPropagation();
alert('click in content')
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to achieve that behaviour?
Thank you.

Edit (more information about what ive already tried)
Change click event for mousedown.
The problem with that is they need to click and drag inside the content, and sometimes the drag beyond the content triggering the container handler.
I cannot use the mousedown.

Comment: I am not sure you could achieve this for your particular use case with just a click or mousedown events. Though, you can try tracking both mousedown and mouseup events, and check with the code which element was first clicked, and where mouse was released.

Comment: Thats the first thing i tried.
The problem with that is they need to click and drag inside the content, and sometimes the drag beyond the content triggering the container handler.
I cannot use the mousedown.

Comment: I don't think you can do this on the "content level", because technically you do make a click on the container. You can only stop the click propagation on the "container level". Mousedown and MouseUp events won't help you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop using the native "click" event, and implement your own synthetic "click" event somehow. You need to listen on both "mousedown" and "mouseup", in order to mimick an "click".

Idea is to attach a one-off "mouseup" handler right inside "mousedown" to synthesize a full "click".

If you "mousedown" in #content, you `stopPropagation` and attach "mouseup" **only** to #content. This way, because #container has no "mouseup" attached, there is no way such synthetic "click" will fire on it.

Comment: I am quite sure that this will not stop the click event from beeing fired on the container. It will emulate a click on the content div, but a click will still be triggered on the container when you mouse-down on the content and mouse-up on the container.

Comment: @Preli you're referring to my partial solution or the full idea?

Comment: your full idea. I had the same / similar idea and even tried to implement it in a jsfiddle. But no mather what you do with your mouseodwn or mouseup events, any click handlers on the container will still be triggered (which is what Albeo wants to avoid if I understood it correctly)

Comment: @Preli You get it wrong. The full idea is to **stop** listening on "click" all at once. OP need to remove any existing "click" listeners, then implement a synthetic "click-like" event by using "mousedown" and "mouseup" together. But your feedback should confirm my partial solution won't work. I'll remove it.

Comment: @Preli I think you're on the right track. I don't have  a computer around me, just typing on phone. If you get a working code example, do post please.

Comment: Quote from question "I dont care about the event in the content, i need to stop the event going trough the container in this situation" ... this sounds like he wants to stop a click event from happening in the container. Listening to other events will not prevent a click from happening ... even if you call stopPropagation in a mouseup handler

Comment: It probably won't. If native "click" is a parallel event mechanism alongside "mousedown/up", then nothing we can do within "mousedown/up" handler will have any effect on "click". This is EXACTLY why I suggest avoid using native "click" and instead, implement a synthetic "click". There's no solution to this problem if you stick to native "click".

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve your problem with "mousedown"?

```
$('#container').on('mousedown', function(ev){
ev.stopPropagation();
alert('click in container')
});

$('#content').on('mousedown', function(ev){
ev.stopPropagation();
alert('click in content w2')
});
```

it triggers immediately

Comment: Thats the first thing i tried.
The problem with that is they need to click and drag inside the content, and sometimes the drag beyond the content triggering the container handler.
I cannot use the mousedown.
Thank you!

Comment: OK, maybe you need jqueryUi. There is a functionallity called draggable. Try total use that. At the moment i cant Test it because im on my Phone .. greetings

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combination of keyup and mosuseup

```
 $('#container').on('keyup', function(ev){
    alert('click in container');
ev.stopPropagation();
});

$('#content').on('mouseup', function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    alert('click in content')
});
```

I hope, it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If there are register functions which are getting called multiple time, then multiple re-register may cause this kind of issue. We need to de-register before re-registering it.

```
$('#youractionidhere').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
  //function body
});
```

Doing `.off()` and then `.on()` event in sequence will be helpful.

Cheers!!!