# JS - Prevent click on parent element

Tags: javascript

I have the following situation:
My user presses and holds the left mouse button on element 1 and releases the mouse button on element 2. This emits a click on the wrapping element. This click should not happen, because the click on the wrapper executes another action, so i can not ignore the click completely on the wrapper.

Even when i use preventDefault or stopPropagation the click is emitted. See my example:

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const one = document.getElementById('one');
const two = document.getElementById('two');
const preventDefault = document.getElementById('preventDefault');
const stopPropagation = document.getElementById('stopPropagation');

const clear = document.getElementById('clear');
clear.addEventListener('click', () => console.clear());

const subscribe = (element) => {
  const eventHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.defaultPrevented ? 'prevented' : '', event.type, 'on', element.id);
    if (preventDefault.checked) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (stopPropagation.checked) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  };
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', eventHandler);
  element.addEventListener('mouseup', eventHandler);
  element.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
};

subscribe(wrapper);
subscribe(one);
subscribe(two);
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}

#one,
#two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#one {
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

#two {
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
Click an hold left mouse button on 1 and release it on 2. Always a click is emitted on wrapper.
<div class="container" id="wrapper">
  wrapper
  <div class="container" id="one">1</div>
  <div class="container" id="two">2</div>
</div>

<div class="toolbar">
  <button id="clear">clear</button>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id='preventDefault'>
    preventDefault
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id='stopPropagation'>
    stopPropagation
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Fun problem! This looks like it's because the click event never actually happens on element 1 nor 2. So stopPropagation() on 1/2 doesn't do anything. Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569371/how-to-stop-propagation-on-click-when-you-release-the-mouse-outside

Answer (score 0):

A `click` event is only emitted on elements if the `mousedown` and `mouseup` happened within this element. You are creating a `mousedown` on 1 and a `mouseup` on 2. The `wrapper` element on the other hand receives `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `click`

Comment: Ok, sound logical. But when i activate stopPropagation on 1 and 2. The mousedown/up never reaches the wrapper, but the click also happens

Comment: there is no ``click`` happening on 1 or 2 so they cannot stop the propagation because their event handlers are not called

Comment: true, but i can prevent the mousedown/up on 1 and 2. But this also dos not work.

Comment: the ``click`` happens wether you stop ``mousedown/mouseup`` regardless, you have to stop the ``click`` directly but you can't because a ``click`` never happens on 1 or 2. Also ``preventDefault`` would not stop this behaviour, those three events will be triggered regardless in that order: ``up -> down -> click`` when within the same element

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you cannot completely ignore the click on the wrapper element, so I assume you want to perform different actions for clicks on `element 1` and `element 2` while still allowing some action to occur when a click happens on the wrapper. You can achieve this by checking which element was the target of the click in your click event handler.

With this code, you can differentiate between clicks on `element 1`, `element 2`, and the wrapper and perform different actions as needed. The wrapper's click event will still occur, but you can handle it separately inside the `handleClick` function.

```js
 const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
 const one = document.getElementById('one');
 const two = document.getElementById('two');
 const preventDefault = 
 document.getElementById('preventDefault');
 const stopPropagation = document.getElementById('stopPropagation');

 const clear = document.getElementById('clear');
 clear.addEventListener('click', () => console.clear());

 let clickStartTime;

 wrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
   clickStartTime = new Date().getTime();
 });

 wrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
   const clickDuration = new Date().getTime() - clickStartTime;
   if (clickDuration < 100) {
     // It's a quick click (not a down-hold-and-release)
     console.log('Quick click on wrapper');
     if (preventDefault.checked) {
       event.preventDefault();
     }
     if (stopPropagation.checked) {
       event.stopPropagation();
     }
   } else {
     // Down-hold-and-release
     console.log('Down-hold-and-release on wrapper');
   }
 });

 one.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   console.log('Clicked on one');
   if (preventDefault.checked) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
   if (stopPropagation.checked) {
     event.stopPropagation();
   }
 });

 two.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   console.log('Clicked on two');
   if (preventDefault.checked) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
   if (stopPropagation.checked) {
     event.stopPropagation();
   }
 });
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}

#one,
#two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#one {
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

#two {
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
Click an hold left mouse button on 1 and release it on 2. Always a click is emitted on wrapper.
<div class="container" id="wrapper">
  wrapper
  <div class="container" id="one">1</div>
  <div class="container" id="two">2</div>
</div>

<div class="toolbar">
  <button id="clear">clear</button>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id='preventDefault'>
    preventDefault
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id='stopPropagation'>
    stopPropagation
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is, that there is no difference between directly click on wrapper and the down-hold-and-release. Both events has the wrapper element as target

Comment: I have update the code 
To achieve differentiation between a direct click on the wrapper and the down-hold-and-release scenario, you can use a combination of mousedown and mouseup events along with a timer to determine if the mouse was held down for a certain duration before release. 
In this solution, we use the mousedown event to record the start time of the click, and then we use the mouseup event to check the duration of the click. If the click duration is less than 100 milliseconds, we consider it a quick click on the wrapper and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Otherwise, we treat it as a down-hold-and-release scenario.

This should differentiate between the two cases and allow you to handle them differently as needed. Adjust the click duration threshold (currently set at 100 milliseconds) as necessary.